# Getting application list without widgets

Tags: android

When I get the list of installed apps, I get them with widgets. However, I don't wanna see widgets because of it's an app launcher. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to narrow your list down to correct category:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( i, 0);
```

Comment: Actually my `list` code is that `List<ApplicationInfo> paketler = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);` Should I change it?

Comment: Yes, because you only want to list those how will show up for `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`, which is what launcher uses (see your Manifest file :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wrote these 3 lines instead of my codes and it works now.